# Plot many arrows in python

Tags: matplotlib, plot, vector

I have the following code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [0.1,0.2]
y = [0.3,0.4]
dx = [0.5,0.5]
dy = [0.5,0.3]

ax = plt.axes()
ax.arrow(x[0], y[0], dx[0], dy[0], head_width=0.09, head_length=0.1)
ax.arrow(x[1], y[1], dx[1], dy[1], head_width=0.09, head_length=0.1)
plt.show()
```

Now imagine that the dimension of `x`, `y`, `dx`, `dy` is a lot larger than 2, let's say 1000. It would be a pain to write 1000 lines by hand for each arrow.

Is there an automatic way to generate all the arrows, given I have the vectors `x`, `y`, `dx`, `dy`?

Comment: You can use a [quiver plot](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.quiver.html) ([example here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/quiver_demo.html)).

Comment: Why not a `for` loop?